# Java Generics `capture<?>` with primitive value (or Double)

Tags: java, android, generics

I am using a charting library which has the following method declaration in it:

```
public float getPixelValueForUserValue(T userValue)...
```

I understand that I should be passing in a generic type, and if I place a breakpoint in my code and simply execute this method using a double value, the code executes and is happy (which I think is to be expected because there appears to be nothing wrong with the code).
Sadly, if I try to write the executed line of code (for example `myobject.getPixelValueForUserValue(2.0)`) then the compiler complains, looking for a `capture<?>` which I need simply to be a double. The error that is produced by the compiler is

> Error:(729, 95) error: incompatible types: Double >cannot be converted to CAP#1
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>   CAP#1 extends Comparable from capture of ?``

If I attempt to dig deeper to see what their `T` is, then as expected its a generic class - but it says that `T extends Comparable<T>`, so I just take this to be that any class I pass to it should extend Comparable, and so I've tried passing it `new Double(myVar)` as `Double` implements Comparable, but alas this fails as well, with the same error...

I have tried creating anonymous methods (perhaps incorrectly) to return the value I need, I have tried creating classes which extend one thing or another. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `T` declared? Can you show the enclosing class's declaration?

Comment: According to [Axis - shinobicharts API](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/android/shinobicharts/latest/apidocs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/Axis.html) the method `getPixelValueForUserValue(T)` belongs to the `Axis<T extends Comparable<T>, U>` class. So in order to understand what types are acceptable by this method, you need to see the generic parameter types of the `Axis` object you are using to call the method. Edit your question to show where you get the `Axis` object from, and its declared generic parameter types. That will make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I needed to pull from the Axis - I misunderstood the scenario and thought I needed to grab the Axis and then attempt to grab the pixel value. The Axis' are typed, and this displayed no compiler warnings (and according to their support forums) is the correct methodology.

```
NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXAxis();
double pixelX = xAxis.getPixelValueForUserValue(targetX);
```